# Modify identical objects inside an array by index

Tags: javascript, arrays

Lets say we have an array and inside that array 2 identical objects such as

```
var myArray = [];
myArray.push({id:1, errorMsg: null});
myArray.push({id:1, errorMsg: null});
```

Why when i am trying to modify my property errorMsg by index , that change would affect both of those objects. E.g

```
myArray[0].errorMsg = 'its an error';
```

Comment: *"Why when i am trying to modify my property errorMsg by index , that change would affect both of those objects. "* - It wouldn't (from your example). Show us your actual code or a **working** example.

Comment: You might have 2 items in your array referring to one object?

Comment: Defining your array this way does not have the behavior you describe.

Comment: Still [not reproduceable](https://jsfiddle.net/sb5dtw74/) ..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

elements of array are references , they might be pointing to same object so changing one reference is reflecting in both places

eg

```
var a = {b:'hi'}
var arr = [a,a]
// if you change 
arr[0].b = 'hello'
// both members of array will change
```

Answer (score 0):

Modifying any `errorMsg` using index will change only that index's value.

Check below example:

```js
    var myArray = [{ id: 1, errorMsg: null },
    { id: 2, errorMsg: null },
    { id: 3, errorMsg: null }]

        
myArray[0].errorMsg = 'its an error';
myArray[2].errorMsg = 'this is last error';

for (i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    console.log(myArray[i].id + ' = ' + myArray[i].errorMsg);
}
```

So your code is correct, there is no error.